# Export data monthly temperature in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

[GEE Link here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/090efd57d0c03712424916b41c0c005c)

I would like to export monthly temperature from TerraClimate, But instead of getting the 12 months period It has index of 9rows and from the year that I desire from 1995 to 2020 I got only until 2004.
This is very confusing to me as I am new to Google Earth Engine.
This also some modification from any post but I couldn't track from where.

```
//var geometry = ee.Point([76.50672654438921,35.35824030837368]);
var fg_points = geometry;
// Set years and month
var startYear = 1995;
var endYear = 2020;
var years = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);
var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);
// load the image collection
//var Daily = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY");
var Daily = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE").select('tmmx');
// make monthly summed mosaics
// loop over the years and months to get summed monthly images
var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(years.map(function(y){
  var yearCollection = Daily.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'));
  var byYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    months.map(function(m) {
      var summedImage = yearCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                  .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()); 
      var date = ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1).format("MM_dd_YYYY");
      return summedImage.set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1)).rename(date);
      //.set('month', m).set('year', y); // eventually set year and month 
  }));
  return byYear;
})).flatten());
// filter the empty one out
var outputMonthly = byMonth.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('system:band_names', 'constant').not())
                    .sort('system:time_start').toBands();
print(outputMonthly);
var features = outputMonthly.reduceRegions(fg_points, ee.Reducer.first(), 30);
print(features);
Export.table.toDrive(features,
"PrecipitationHTL",
"PrecipitationHTL",
"PrecipitationHTL");
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you should watch product description [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/IDAHO_EPSCOR_TERRACLIMATE). There, you can observe it is a monthly product, not daily, with a scale of 0.1 (in ºC). So, between '1995-01-01' and '2021-01-01' (your dates) must have 312 images; as effectively I could corroborate. So, you can export directly your data to Google drive with a different function. In following [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/cefc827c968351750837524b78158df8), I used your point (76.50672654438921,35.35824030837368) for retrieving and exporting data to my Google Drive. It looks as follows:

```
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(76.50672654438921,35.35824030837368);

Map.centerObject(pt);
Map.addLayer(pt);

var starDate = '1995-01-01';
var endDate = '2021-01-01';

var Monthly = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE").select('tmmx')
  .filterDate(starDate, endDate);

print(Monthly);

var allDates = ee.List(Monthly.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));

var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  });

print(allDatesSimple);

var getTemp = function(image) {

  // Reducing region and getting value
  var value_tmmx = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), pt)
    .get('tmmx');

  return ee.Number(value_tmmx).multiply(0.1);

};

var count = Monthly.size();

var tmmx_list = Monthly.toList(count).map(getTemp);

print("tmmx_list", tmmx_list);

var paired = allDatesSimple.zip(tmmx_list);

print ("paired", paired);

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(paired.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'date': ee.String(el.get(0)),
    'tmmx':ee.Number(el.get(1))
  });
}));

//print(myFeatures);

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"export_tmmx", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder
"tmmx_pt",  //file name
"CSV");
```

After running above script in GEE code editor, I exported successfully CSV file to Google drive. An extract of 312 paired values (dates and tmax) can be observed as follows. It is a very cold area.

```
system:index,date,tmmx,.geo
0,1995-01-01,-21.8,
1,1995-02-01,-19.0,
2,1995-03-01,-15.9,
3,1995-04-01,-10.3,
4,1995-05-01,-1.4000000000000001,
5,1995-06-01,4.2,
6,1995-07-01,8.6,
7,1995-08-01,7.7,
8,1995-09-01,3.2,
9,1995-10-01,-1.7000000000000002,
10,1995-11-01,-8.4,
.
.
.
302,2020-03-01,-13.5,
303,2020-04-01,-7.5,
304,2020-05-01,-0.4,
305,2020-06-01,5.4,
306,2020-07-01,9.4,
307,2020-08-01,9.4,
308,2020-09-01,5.7,
309,2020-10-01,2.1,
310,2020-11-01,-6.1000000000000005,
311,2020-12-01,-14.700000000000001,
```